# Find a string which has leading space and add line exactly below to add line

Tags: sed

I have a file like below.

```
    # Start OF Java_Out_Of_Memory
    - displayName: "Java_Out_Of_Memory"
      logDirectory: "/opt/xyz"
      logName: "TextLog_*"
      searchStrings:
         - displayName: "Out_Of_Memory"
           pattern: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
           matchExactString: false
           caseSensitive: false 
    # End OF Java_Out_Of_Memory
```

I wanted to add line exactly below of caseSensitive: false with printMatchesString: false...

```
# Start OF Java_Out_Of_Memory
    - displayName: "Java_Out_Of_Memory"
      logDirectory: "/opt/xyz"
      logName: "TextLog_*"
      searchStrings:
          #displayName Should be unique across the patterns including the case.
         - displayName: "Out_Of_Memory"
           pattern: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
           matchExactString: false
           caseSensitive: false  
           printMatchedString: false
# End OF Java_Out_Of_Memory
```

I don't know how many lead space of matched string... Leading space may vary depends on file to file.

I tried this

```
sed -i '/^[^#]*caseSensitive:*/a \\         printMatchedString: false'
```

So my requirement is to add a line exactly below and even consider lead space

NOTE:- I have multi configuration like above and I need add PrinitMatched string on every configuration

Comment: Does this work? `sed -E 's/^ .*/&0\n/' myfile.txt`

Comment: @Bohemian How does that add the `printMatchedString` line?

Comment: @Bohemian `sed` uses `&` in the replacement string to get the match, not `$0`.

Comment: @Barmar thx m8! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -E '/^[^#]*caseSensitive:/ {p; s/^([[:blank:]]*)[^[:blank:]].*$/\1printMatchesString: false/;}' myfile.txt
```

Explanation:

- `/^[^#]*caseSensitive:/` - on lines matching "caseSensitive:" (not preceded by "#"
- `{` - do the following block of commands
- `p` - print the current line (in its original form)
- `s/^([[:blank:]]*)[^[:blank:]].*$/\1printMatchesString: false/` - parse the line as a bunch of blanks (in parens, so it's a capture group) and then whatever's left, and replace it with the blanks (`\1` recalls the capture group) and "printMatchesString: false". Note that the result will be printed automatically.
- `}` - marks the end of the group of commands

Comment: why -i[SUFFIX] is not working for this sed and not even sed -e, only sed -E working

Comment: The `-E` option to `sed` makes it use "extended" regular expression syntax; you could do the same thing without `-E`, but you'd need to rewrite the patterns into "basic" regular expression syntax. `-e` just indicates that what follows it is an expression, so it doesn't really do anything here (it's mainly useful if you want to specify more than one expression). And as I said, `-i` does in-place modification of the file, which is what caused the problem you had where only the first iteration did anything.